# An exception for a circular reference database - is this one?

Tags: database, database-design, circular-reference

I have 4 tables, linked in a circular reference - I remember from college that I was told this is bad however there are exceptions...I am hoping that this is one of them :)

My database contains 4 tables; teachers, classes, subjects and teachers_classes.

The following sums up my relationships:

- A teacher can have many classes
- A class can have many teachers (so teachers_classes eliminates the many-to-many here).
- A class can have many subjects
- A subject can only have 1 class
- A teacher can have many subjects

If you can visualise this, my ERD looks like a square (or circle)... I have already built my simple app, and was prompted by someone else to check this problem.. please someone tell me ths is an exception and why? I cannot remember any of the stuff I was taught about this, but my application appears to work totally fine for what I want it to do!

Comment: Which table contains teacher-subject relationships?

Comment: there is not a teacher-subject relationship, a subject can only have 1 teacher! This is something I plan on changing for further work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Circular references can be bad for a couple of reasons:

1. In the case where the relationships *must* exist (i.e., a teacher *must* have a class and a class *must* have a teacher, both from a business and technical requirement perspective), you run into a chicken-or-the-egg scenario: you can't add a teacher without a class, nor can you add a class without a teacher.
2. It makes it difficult to figure out what's at the "top" of the heirarchy (since, truthfully, there isn't a "top")

Assuming that you can have teachers without classes and/or subjects without classes, it sounds like one of those two would be the "top" (from a business perspective, I'd assume that it would be subjects).

If what you have is working, I don't see an issue with the design, nor do I see an alternative way of designing it.

---

**Edit after comment**

There isn't an issue with one-sided dependency (that's just what a plain ol' non-nullable foreign key is).

I feel like I should point out something as well, based upon your comment: the objections to circular dependencies are *technical*, not *logical*. If the business says that there can be no teachers without classes and no classes without teachers, that's fine; you just can't model the data that way or you'll never be able to add anything. You have to define which one of those objects--classes or teachers--is allowed to exist in isolation (from a technical perspective, not a business one).

You're somewhat saved by the fact that you have a M:M relationship between teachers and classes, because this forces you to make *both* able to exist in isolation (since the connection is made in a link table, rather than in the participant tables themselves.

Because of this, you do not have a true circular dependency. Your business logic is circular, but that's fine, since you have complete control over how it operates. Your layout either looks like this:

```
   Teacher <----- TeacherClass -----> Class
      ^                                 ^
      |                                 |
      |                                 |
TeacherSubject --------------------> Subject
```

(If a teacher can have multiple subjects)

Or this:

```
   Teacher <----- TeacherClass -----> Class
      |                                 ^
      |                                 |
      |                                 |
      \----------------------------> Subject
```

(If a teacher can have only one subject)

Or this:

```
   Teacher <----- TeacherClass -----> Class
      ^                                 ^
      |                                 |
      |                                 |
      \----------------------------- Subject
```

(If a subject can have only one teacher)

In the first case, both `Teacher` and `Class` are top-level entities, since neither of them points to anything else (the link tables accomplish this). In the second, only `Class` is a top-level entity.

As long as there's a top-level entity somewhere on the path, you're fine. In the first, you can add records in this order:

```
Teacher -> Class -> (TeacherClass -> Subject) -> TeacherSubject
```

(I enclosed `TeacherClass -> Subject` in parens because you could add those in any order)

In the second, you can add them in this order:

```
Class -> Subject -> Teacher -> TeacherClass
```

In the third, you can add them in this order:

```
Class -> Teacher -> (TeacherClass -> Subject)
```

So, from a technical perspective, you don't have a true circular dependency.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Adam, what you have mentioned in (1) with the chicken and egg scnerio is what I have but is infact what I require? Because a class cannot be created without a teacher being assigned to it, however you can add a teacher without there being a class.

I don't really have a "top" table, should there be one? You cannot have subjects without classes; teachers are created, then the class (assigned to the teacher), and then subject (assigned to the class) if that makes sense...

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer Adam...I should really have mentioned that a teacher can have many subjects, however a subject can only have 1 teacher...so i think your second example applies to me more so. thanks.

Comment: @Yvonne: Thanks, you presented a third possibility that I hadn't accounted for. While this has already solved your problem and been accepted, I've edited my answer to include that scenario as well.

Comment: this is a perfect answer. thanks so much. I am trying to understand why circular reference is bad